# Retreiving data from Fingerprint Time & Attendance System Connected to the Network

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming, communication, device, biometrics

I am currently working on creating application for Bio Metric Time and attendance system, which stores the time details into its own memory. The current software (delphi Application) provided with that retrieves data from the device does not meet the need of the Customer and it is in Chinese Language Half the way.

I am tasked to work on retrieving data from the device. I am a dot net programmer and I have no idea on Device communication. I tried network packet sniffer to understand the packets sent across. but that does not give much info.

Any right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can try "Fingerprint 1.0" software. it is available on this link. its free to download.
http://fingerprint-attendance-system.fyxm.net/

Answer (score 0):

i am in the same research, from Venezuela, i just found this

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/125530/FingerPrint-machine.aspx

I am now testing to get the data from the marchine, to retrieve the data when i check up and analyze it

It would be nice if we keep in touch helping each other

P.D.: sorry for my bad english

Comment: I´m working with an Anviz Ep300, just noticed that the open port is 21 (FTP), still researching, contact me ricardojriosr@gmail.com

Comment: there is any solution or not @ricardorios

Comment: @ChitraNandpal still nothing

Answer (score 0):

i just found two SDK to work with network devices.

Just as i told you i have an ANVIZ EP300, but still couldn´t make it work with this SDK because is it in Visual Basic (old) and i work with C# 2010.

Just in case here is ANVIZ SDK

http://www.microcom.com.ar/anviz/sdk.rar

If someone can translate it to C# and make it work, i would be very happy :D

And i found Suprema Products SDK too, but i do not have a Suprema Device to test it

http://www.fingerprint-it.com/Downloader.aspx?dir=Downloads/SDKs&file=BioStar%201.26%20SDK.zip

Just tell me the brand of your device and i will research too